My MCMC Simulation
I am new to MCMC Simulation and Bayesian Analysis, so I wonder if my simulation has converged.
My posterior is highly correlated by nature, so I'm facing some difficulty to ensure a sufficient number of samples. Corrently I'm using the last 5,000 samples of each of the 10 chains.
I would be very happy if someone could give me his opinion on this subject!







I agree with your choice of burn in. You can verify the level of MCMC error by rerunning the process with several different initial conditions.
